# How to implement a request-response pattern with paho mqtt java?

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

I'd like to use [Paho MQTT Java](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java) and implement some "request-response" pattern. What I mean by that is that in some instances the client has to talk to the server and expects a specific answer to a specific request. It feels like this lib has everything needed to match a request and a response, but I can't quite put it together.

I found I can retrieve a token via `deliveryComplete`, and that I can do a `setActionCallback` on this token. But first, I'm not entirely sure what an "action" means. Then, if it means what I think it means, how to get the actual response to my request from there?

```java
sampleClient.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(topic);
        System.out.println("setCallback: "+ message.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
        System.out.println(token.getMessageId());
        token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                var response = asyncActionToken.getResponse();

                try {
                    System.out.println(new String(response.getPayload()));
                } catch (MqttException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using MQTT5.

This is how it works:
Suppose you have two MQTT clients, one of which acts as a server.
client1, client2(server).
client1 publishes a message with a response topic in the message property.
client2 receives the message reads the message properties and publishes the response on that topic
client 1 gets the message on the response topic.

**Here is a small implementation:**

Use the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-paho-mqtt5</artifactId>
    <version>3.17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Client 1 Publish:

```
public void sendMessage(String messageStr){
    MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage();
    MqttProperties properties = new MqttProperties();
    properties.setResponseTopic("response");
    properties.setCorrelationData("correlation".getBytes());
    message.setProperties(properties);
    message.setPayload(messageStr.getBytes());
    message.setQos(1);
    message.setRetained(true);
    try {
        client.publish("test",message);
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Client 2 (Server) Subscriber MessageListener:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.IMqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client.IMqttMessageListener;
import org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.common.MqttMessage;
import org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.common.packet.MqttProperties;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class MessageListener implements IMqttMessageListener {
    @Autowired
    private IMqttClient client;

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
        log.info("Topic : {}, Message: {}", topic,message.toString());
        MqttProperties properties = new MqttProperties();
        if(message.getProperties()!=null && StringUtils.hasText(message.getProperties().getResponseTopic())){
            MqttMessage responseMessage = new MqttMessage();
            properties.setCorrelationData(message.getProperties().getCorrelationData());
            responseMessage.setProperties(properties);
            responseMessage.setPayload("Response".getBytes());
            responseMessage.setQos(1);
            responseMessage.setRetained(true);
            client.publish(message.getProperties().getResponseTopic(),responseMessage);
        }

    }
}
```

Then Client 1 should subscribe to topic "response" to receive the response from client 2.

Here is more on this:

http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqttv5-request-response/

Comment: This is a link only answer that will be useless as soon as the link breaks. Answers should contain all the relevant details and links should only for context. This answer will be deleted if not updated.

Comment: I felt, it is too little space to write an entire article on how MQTT5 request-response model works. But tried to squeeze in an example. And probably show the generosity, to appreciate the answer, as other answers are merely suggestion on how NOT to do it using MQTT.

Comment: Better yet you can directly use the `eclipse paho mqtt5 client` [1]. I think the reffered `camel-paho-mqtt` is a wrapper around `eclipse-paho` client.

[1] https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client/1.2.5

Answer (score 0):

MQTT is overkill for any kind of 1 Request - 1 Response....that is what APIs are for.  MQTT is best for one node sending out data to one or more nodes who are tapped into the Topic.  The sending node (Publisher) doesn't need to know about any of the receiving nodes (Subscribers)...they just all have to agree on the Topic used.

That being said, you could implement a "Query" Publish, and look for a "Reply" MQTT message back that you would subscribe to.  I have done this it the past where multiple nodes can benefit from knowing what the Reply is.  So it might look something like this:  Publish - `q/system/status` and Subscribe to `r/system/status` or `r/system/#`.

Comment: It's not overkill if that is what you have already. MQTT 5.0 specifically adds this as a feature, for "business ACKs", where not only does the client need to know that the message was delivered, but also the result. Look up Request Response for more details.

Answer (score -2):

There is NO end to end delivery notification in the MQTT protocol. The delivery complete callback is only called to notify that the message has travelled between the publishing client and the broker, it says nothing about if the message has been delivered to any down stream subscribers (there could 0 to many other clients subscribed to a given topic).

Once a message reaches the broker it may even be queued for an offline client with a persistent session.

Even assuming just 1 client receives the message, any reply would be a totally separate  message not linked to the first request.

MQTT is not natively a request/response system like say HTTP, it's a way to send messages to 0 to many clients that have subscribed to a give topic.

MQTT v5 starts to introduce the concepts of requests/response to MQTT, but even then it's just an extra optional slot in the header to include a topic to reply on. And you can set a collation id in the message header to link the response message to the request.